# How can I share vsvimrc file across different versions of Visual Studio

Tags: vsvim

Recently I installed two versions of Visual Studio on the same machine with VSVim extensions. Because they differ in functionality they require different settings in the `vsvimrc` file and that is the problem.

Is it possible to share the same `vsvimrc` file between different versions of Visual Studio but select slightly different configuration based on the version?

Comment: What settings do you want to be different between the versions?

Comment: In one version I want to map Resharper commands whereas in the second I want to make use of the native functionality of VS.

Comment: Do you need to have both live at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the exact parameters of your problem, you could do several things. For one, you could put the base of common functionality in your `_vsvimrc` and put the difference in a separate file for each version and then just source that file when you start Visual Studio. That requires a manual step of sourcing the file, but it could work.